# Wireguard peer as an internet gateway

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I have a Debian server with Wireguard installed and want to connect to it from my phone in a way, that Debian server will act as a phone's gateway to the internet. So all internet traffic from the phone will go through WG tunnel to the Debian server and from there to the internet.

Debian server's WG config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51194
PrivateKey = ***Debian server***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***myPhone***
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32
```

MyPhone WG config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***myPhone***
Address = 10.10.10.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***Debian server***
Endpoint = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51194
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

I set up `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (and restarted the server).

My iptables rules od a Debian server are:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

From my phone I can connect to the Debian server through WG and can ping it (`ping 10.10.10.1` works, the other way also works), however, internet on a phone is not working.

I suspect some problem with iptables. Any idea?

Comment: You need to investigate deeper. What _other_ iptables rules do you have in both of those chians? (Remember that -A just appends to the end...) When the phone tries to access the internet, what does it get stuck at – what kind of packets does the server see from the phone on its wg0 (especially what's being retransmitted over and over)? Is it making DNS queries or is it trying to establish TCP connections? When some packets arrive at the server's wg0, do they also show up as leaving through ens3 – and if they do show up, are they correctly NATed by "-j MASQUERADE"? And same for replies ens3→wg0

Comment: Actually, this are all iptables rules I have. I wanted to start with some basic rules and then build up.

Comment: Can you verify that even tests to IP addresses rather than DNS addresses fail on the phone? This was already asked by user1686 but you forgot to answer *ALL* of the questions (there are still other questions asked that you should address)

Comment: Found a problem. iPhone needs DNS= directive in config, while Android works without that.